# Navigation Drawer not going to previous pages when back is pressed

Tags: flutter

I have a navigation drawer in  my dashboard page.I have few listTiles on the drawer when i click on each items it opens a new page.When i open a few pages then when i click on the back button then the app closes fully.I want to see the previous pages that i have opened and then close the app when the last page found in the stack     .

```
final drawerItems = [
new DrawerItem("Home", Icons.home),
new DrawerItem("Profile", Icons.person),
new DrawerItem("Change Password", Icons.lock),
new DrawerItem("Link CCID", Icons.calendar_view_day),
new DrawerItem("Settings", Icons.settings),
new DrawerItem("Allergies", Icons.opacity),
new DrawerItem("Logout", Icons.power_settings_new),
];

 _getDrawerItemScreen(int  pos) {
debugPrint("Position $pos");
if(pos==0)
{
  setState(() {
    title="Home";
  });
  return new Home(drawerItem: drawerItems[_selectedIndex]);
}
else if(pos==1)
{
  setState(() {
    title="My Profile";
  });
  return new ProfilePage(drawerItem: drawerItems[_selectedIndex],title: "My Profile",);
}
else if(pos==2)
{
  setState(() {
    title="Change Password";
  });
  return new ChangePassword(drawerItem: drawerItems[_selectedIndex],title: "Change Password",);
}
else if(pos==3)
{
  setState(() {
    title="LinkCCid";
  });
  return new LinkCcid(drawerItem: drawerItems[_selectedIndex],title: "LinkCCid",);
}
else if(pos==4)
{
  setState(() {
    title="Settings";
  });
//  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>Settings(drawerItem: drawerItems[_selectedIndex],title: "Settings",)));
  return new Settings(drawerItem: drawerItems[_selectedIndex],title: "Settings",);
}
else if(pos==5)
{
  setState(() {
    title="Allergies";
  });
  return new Allergies(drawerItem: drawerItems[_selectedIndex],title: "Allergies",);
}
else if(pos==6)
{
  _logout();
}
}


 _onSelectItem(int index) {
setState(() {
  _selectedIndex = index;
  _getDrawerItemScreen(_selectedIndex);
});
Navigator.of(context).pop(); // close the drawer
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `Navigator` and use it's `push()` method to add a new page in the `Navigator` stack.

You can check the official documentation to implement a basic navigation: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics

However, I don't think it's recommended to add pages from a drawer menu entry in the navigator stack. The user could add a large number of pages to the stack and have to press the back button a lot to exit the application.